# Radio button List not Display Properly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am used a RadioButtonList in my Page. also I used updatepanel on this Page.My problem is RadionButtonList  display only item name no roundclick in the time of Page load . it will show with round after cliking one of the any control in the page,means after a postback .this RadiobuttonList am using in another pages but it works properly.

my code is below:

```
   <form id="form1"  runat="server">
      <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
     </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>   
     <fieldset>
      <table class="ui-accordion" >                            
     <tr>                               
      <td align="left" colspan="2"class="style2">
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbSelection" style="margin-left:120px;" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="12"   CellSpacing="1"                                                     onselectedindexchanged="RbSelection_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">                                            
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Department</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Section</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </td>
  </tr>
    </table>
   </fieldset>
       </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please post the styles code also

Comment: I think this is the problem `style="margin-  left:120px;"`

Comment: Rahul Nikate this same control used in another page .but no problem on that page.

Comment: Give a try by removing all styles from `table` `<td>` and `RadioButtonList`

Comment: Probably an issue related with your styling. Otherwise control is coming out fine. Please post your related style code as well.